# How to place KVM VMs on several hosts in the same network, with one of the VMs as the DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, kvm-virtualization, vlan, trunk

I have a KVM host running on Centos. I have 3 Virtual machines installed on this host. Host is connected to a Nexus (Cisco). Virtual machine is able to get Internet. Everything is working fine. Now I need to make one of the Virtual machine as a DHCP server for Virtual machines which are running on another hyper-visor. Both hyper-visors are in same subnet.

How can I make it possible ?

Any Help ??

Regards
Nix.

Answer (score 0):

Set up bridges on the hosts, use those bridges with the VMs. This will make all the hosts and VMs speak in the same network, so you can install any service on a VM and this service will be available in the entire network.